# The better (and the less expensive) way to find a GameObject?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine

I have a great perplexity, and I hope someone can give me some advice :)

In term of performance, what is the less ‘expensive' way in order to find a gameobject?

1)

```
public GameObject myGO;
```

2)

```
GameObject myGO = this.transform.parent.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject;
```

3)

```
GameObject myGO = GameObject.Find("myObject")
```

Comment: I'd say setting it to the script directly in the editor

Answer (score 0):

1 is the fastest as you already have the reference in your variable. No computation necessary.

In 2, you have a couple of reference redirections, which is fast. You also have function calls to get the zeroth item, which also should be fast enough. I'd say this is the second best.

In 3, Unity is looking for the name among the gameobjects in the scene. I don't know the implementation details--unless they are doing some kind of hashing, there will be a number of string comparisons. Either way, this feels like the slowest one.

However, you don't need to worry about efficiency of such code unless you are doing 100s of this in a frame. Worry more about object instantiations if you want to make your game more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The Find method is not recommended not just because of performance cost - basing code on stuff having to be named in a specific way on the scene is a bad habit. In case name of the object changes for any reason, you will not be able to find your object anwyays.

Answer (score 0):

My strategy to avoid the store of a reference is to use parent and child method (your 2 way)! Example:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html

It's fast compared to Find and you don't need to store the reference.

Sure the 1 is fast but it's much less convenient, that's why I do not always use it.

PS. If you need to get the main camera reference there is a even better way

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html